# Content stick to banner onScroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a banner that shrinks on scroll and some content below it, how can I get the content to stick on the banner for a few seconds before moving? I tried using the jQuery plugin stickem, but it doesn't seem to work.

JS:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>175){
        // animate fixed div to small size:
        $('.wrapper').stop().animate({ height: 57 , 'padding-top': 50},100);
        $('.text').stop().animate({ 'bottom': 50},100);
    } else {
        //  animate fixed div to original size
        $('.wrapper').stop().animate({ height: 300, 'padding-top': 0},100);
        $('.text').stop().animate({ 'bottom': 150},100);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bnsUB/259/

Comment: What do you mean by "stick on the banner"?

Comment: on the example in jsfiddle, there is a banner.
when you scroll the page the banner will shrink.
i want the ALL of the content to be under the banner ('stick') for a few seconds when you scroll the page.

Comment: http://davist11.github.io/jQuery-Stickem/ so something like where the heading is where it stays for a few seconds then moves again, but under my banner not top of the page

Answer (score 0):

I normally dont suggest plugins, but Waypoints is a pretty good one for something like this.

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/